# ¿Cómo obtener y cargar los resultados de org chart en un array con php?

Tags: mysql, php8, orgchart

Estoy intentando cargar los resultados que obtengo desde una base de datos mysql en un array, cree esta función que obtiene los datos desde el archivo cargar.php

> Funcion: PHPtoOrgChart.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.orgchart.css" />
<script src="jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function PHPtoOrgChart() {
        var members;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cargar.php',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {

                members = $.parseJSON(data)

            }
        })
        console.log(members);

        for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {

            var member = members[i];

            if (i == 0) {
                $("#chart-container2").append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + 
            member.otherInfo + "</li>")
            } else {

                if ($('#pr_' + member.parentId).length <= 0) {
                    $('#' + member.parentId).append("<ul id='pr_" + member.parentId + 
                     "'><li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li></ul>")

                } else {
                    $('#pr_' + member.parentId).append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
                }

            }
        }

        $("#chart-container2").orgChart({
            container: $("#chart-container"),
            interactive: true,
            fade: true,
            speed: 'slow'
        });

    });
</script>
```

Luego en mi archivo mostrar php tengo un array y sub arrays que deberian ordenar los resultados según los que obtenga desde la función PHPtoOrgChart lo que quiero lograr es ordenar los resultados con arrays en lugar de utilizar el script de la función PHPtoOrgChart, pero utilizando los estilos del script de org-chart, alguien podria ayudarme por favor.

> Funcion: mostrar.php
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>
> <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
>     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style.css" />
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <?phP
>     include 'PHPtoOrgChart.php';
>
>     for ($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++) {
>
>         $data = array(
>
>             'Principal' => array(
>                 "codigo" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['parentId']),
>                 'Secundario' => array(
>                     "miembro" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['memberId']),
>                     "info" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['otherInfo']),
>                 ),
>             ),
>         );
>         echo '<div style="display: none">
> <ul id="chart-container2" class="clearfix"></ul>
> </div>
> <div id="chart-container">
>
> </div>';
>         PHPtoOrgChart($data);
>         echo '</div>';
>     }
>
>     ?>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

archivo de cosulta a la base de datos cargar.php

```html
<?php
function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="php81.com";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbname="tree";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
    $sql = "select iduser as memberId, parent as parentId  ,user as otherInfo from users";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($wines);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¡Podrian ayudarme por favor!

Comment: Te sugiero que montes un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que ilustre de la forma más sencilla tu duda. Piensa que este sitio no está pensado para depurar errores, replantear casos de uso, ni resolver ejercicios escolares, el objetivo es utilizar las dudas concretas como ejemplos para ilustrar conceptos mucho más generales que sirvan para resolver dudas similares a futuros usuarios. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]